# How do I add a target=_blank to php code to open in new window?

Tags: php

I have a simple link that looks like this in php code:

```
<a class="feed-link" title="<?php echo esc_attr(sprintf( $rss['feedtitle'], 
get_bloginfo('name'), $rss['separator'] )); ?>" href="<?php echo get_feed_link(); ?>">

<img alt="img" src="<?php echo FEEDBURNER_EMAIL_SUBSCRIPTION_URL; ?>/img/rss.png" />Posts 
<abbr title="Really Simple Syndication">RSS</abbr></a>
```

How would I add a target="_blank" into that chunk of php code so it doesn't take the user off my page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an HTML attribute of the `<a>` tag so you add it to your HTML.

```
<a target="_blank" class="feed-link" title="<?php echo esc_attr(sprintf( 
$rss['feedtitle'], get_bloginfo('name'), $rss['separator'] )); ?>" href="<?php echo get_feed_link(); ?>">
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond, John. I didn't realize it would be that easy.  Works perfectly now.  Thanks!